# Automatic alias overriding manual alias on each edit

Tags: 6, path-aliases

Does anyone have an issue with Automatic alias, where the setting keeps turning back to auto on each edit of a node?

What we would like to achieve is

a) some node paths should be generated automatically from the title and remain automatically managed

b) for other paths we want to override the alias

The problem is only with b, where after any edit to the node the alias behavior reverts back to a.

How to get desired behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Go to admin/build/path/pathauto on your site, open the 'General settings' fieldset and select 'Do nothing. Leave the old alias intact.' as update action. That should be all.